# Upload multiple images in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, multipartform-data

I want to upload multiple images to the server using Alamofire.

All things work fine, however, only one image gets uploaded. I need to upload multiple images, or more, depending on the user logged in as. I'm using a library called `DKImagePickerController` to pick the images from gallery or from camera.

```
func upload() {

    //shortcuts
    let id = userr.integer(forKey: "id")
    let plateId = plateIdTextField.text!
    let customerName = customerNameTextField.text!
    let customerContact = customerContactTextField.text!
    let package = radioButtonsController.selectedIndex + 1

    var parameters: [String: Any]
    parameters = ["user_id": id,
                  "package": package,
                  "plate_id": plateId,
                  "customer_name": customerName,
                  "customer_contact": customerContact]

    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity?.labelText = "uploading.."
    spinningActivity?.detailsLabelText = "Please wait"

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for fileImage in self.fileUIImage {
            multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(fileImage)!, withName: "image", fileName:"image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
        }
    },
                     to: uploadURL,
                     method: HTTPMethod(rawValue: "POST")!,
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {

                        case .success(let upload, _, _):

                            upload.responseJSON { response in

                                //Unpacking
                                guard let result = response.result.value else { return }
                                spinningActivity!.hide(true)
                                print("\(result)")
                                self.BackToHomePage()
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Completely unrelated, instead of `HTTPMethod(rawValue: "POST")!`, you could just use `.post`. Less syntactic noise and avoids potential for simple typographical errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to send multiple files.

1. You can use a unique `name` for each file (in this case, `name` values of `image0`, `image1`, etc.):

   ```
   for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
       multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, withName: "image\(index)", fileName: "image\(index).png", mimeType: "image/png")
   }
   ```

   That results in a `$_FILES` of:

   ```
   $_FILES =     {
       image0 =         {
           error = 0;
           name = "image0.png";
           size = 23578;
           "tmp_name" = "/tmp/php1bc19G";
           type = "image/png";
       };
       image1 =         {
           error = 0;
           name = "image1.png";
           size = 338685;
           "tmp_name" = "/tmp/phpcGS5d6";
           type = "image/png";
       };
   };
   ```

   (Ignore the format of this output, but rather just focus on the key/value combinations in this nested directory structure: In terms of what this output is, I had web service send `$_FILES` back as JSON, I then let Alamofire parse it, and this is how the resulting dictionary was output in my client app.)
2. Alternatively, you can use an array for the `name` by including a `[]` after the field name, e.g., literally `image[]`:

   ```
   for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
       multipartFormData.append(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, withName: "image[]", fileName: "image\(index).png", mimeType: "image/png")
   }
   ```

   That results in the following to be received on the server:

   ```
   $_FILES =     {
       image =         {
           error =             (
               0,
               0
           );
           name =             (
               "image0.png",
               "image1.png"
           );
           size =             (
               23578,
               338685
           );
           "tmp_name" =             (
               "/tmp/phpI4XrwU",
               "/tmp/php3kVhhl"
           );
           type =             (
               "image/png",
               "image/png"
           );
       };
   };
   ```

It just depends upon how the web service was expecting the request to be created.